# How to calculate slope and aspect ratio values by giving latitude, longitude and elevation data as input?

Tags: r, terrain

As I have no much idea regarding the calculation of slope, Can anyone help me with the code that can calculate slope and aspect ration values?

I have latitude, longitude and elevation values in a file.
Is there any method to get these values?

I searched a lot and got to know there is a function called "terrain" in R, which gives slope and aspect ratio. But I got nan values everywhere.

Comment: Please put a [mcve] in your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using some dummy data:

```
library(raster)

long <- rep(rep(seq(12,36,0.5),41))
lat <-rep(seq(32,52,0.5), each=49)
dat <- rnorm(2009, 26.5, 44.0)

data <- data.frame(long, lat, dat)

rast <- rasterFromXYZ(data)
crs(rast) <- "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs "

slope <- terrain(rast,opt = 'slope', unit = 'degrees')
aspect <- terrain(rast, opt = 'aspect', unit = 'degrees')
flowdir <- terrain(rast, opt = 'flowdir')

spplot(stack(rast, slope, aspect, flowdir), scales = list(draw = T)) # the legend is not correct - only for demonstration purposes
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helped me. I am able to get the output for this code. I will try for my dataset and see.

Comment: class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 15, 29, 435  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0001515621, 0.0001445789  (x, y)
extent     : 77.55591, 77.5603, 12.89393, 12.8961  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : slope 
values     : 6.670107e-09, 89.99732  (min, max)

Comment: The above text is the output I got. How can I get actual values of slope for each point?

Comment: rasterToPoints(slope, spatial = F) # if you want to plot the points as spatial objects, you put T; you can transform the raster to a matrix as well -use as.matrix(slope)

Comment: ya I am getting it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Irrespective of the number of input points, I am getting 118 output points. What does that mean? I needed slope and aspect values for each point I am giving as input. But on the output even X and Y values are changed.

Comment: not sure if I understand. X and Y should be the same since these are representing the coordinates of the raster. The output is giving you for every point of latitude/longitude the value of the raster (slope or anything else)

Comment: " +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 " Can you please elaborate what is the meaning of this line? Do numbers 52, 10, 4321000 and 3210000 Specify anything in particular?